# Error inPackage Manager Console in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#

I have a problems when I open Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2019 and I can't get request "Add-Migration".
this is description about my error.
thanks you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTCG9.png)

Comment: It looks like you have two errors.  You first have to solve the issue with loading init.ps1.  Fixing the first error will probably solve 2nd.  Check if the path to init.ps1 is valid and you have read permission of the file.

Comment: jdweng I don't know how to fix init.ps1. Can you show me? thanks you